# Multiple activities or fragments for buttons

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a layout that contains 8 buttons, each of which is supposed to display a list of items from a text file. Would it be considered bad practice to use intents to create multiple activities or should I use fragments instead?

Answer (score 0):

you can send your text file address with intent and check it in next activity and create list from it .dont need create multiple activity.